# Expected value of the product of two dependent random variables

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, binomial-distribution, point-processes

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be Binomial point process in $W = [0, 6] \times [0, 4]$ with $n$ points. Let $A_1 = [0, 2] \times [0, 4]$, $A_2 = [0, 6] \times [0, 2]$, and $A_3 = [2, 6] × [2, 4]$. I want to find $E[N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_1) N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_2)]$, where $N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_1)$ is the number of points from $\mathbf{X}$ in $A_1$ and $N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_2)$ is the number of points from $\mathbf{X}$ in $A_2$. It is clear that $N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_1)$ and $N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_2)$ are dependent, but we can see from $A_1 = [0, 2] \times [0, 4]$ and $A_2 = [0, 6] \times [0, 2]$ that they're also **not** disjoint. If these were disjoint, then I would know how to calculate $E[N_{\mathbf{X}}(A) N_{\mathbf{X}}(B)]$ using the multinomial distribution, but I'm not sure how to calculate this.

I calculated that $E[N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_1)] = \dfrac{8}{24} = \dfrac{1}{3}$ and $E[N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_2)] = \dfrac{12}{24} = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

I then try to calculate $E[N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_1) N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_2)]$ using conditional expectation:

$$
\begin{align*}
E[N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_1) N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_2)] &= E[N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_1)]E[N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_2) | N_{\mathbf{X}}(A_1)] \\
&= \left( n \cdot p_1 \right) \left( (n - r) \cdot p_2 \right) \ \ \ \text{(where $n - r$ is the number of points in $A_2$ that are not in $A_1$.)} \\
&= n^2 p_1 p_2 \cdot (1 - r/n) \\
&= n^2 \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{r}{n} \right) \\
&= \frac{n}{6} \left( n - r \right).
\end{align*}
$$

But I'm not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A_1$ and $A_2$ are not disjoint, however parts of them are so.

$\begin{align}\mathsf E(N_\mathbf{X}(A_1)N_\mathbf{X}(A_2))&=\mathsf E(N_\mathbf X((A_1\cap A_2)\cup(A_1\smallsetminus A_2))~N_\mathbf X((A_1\cap A_2)\cup(A_2\smallsetminus A_1)))\\[2ex]&=\mathsf E(N_\mathbf X^2(A_1\cap A_2))+\mathsf E(N_\mathbf X(A_1\cap A_2)~N_\mathbf X((A_1\smallsetminus A_2)\cup(A_2\smallsetminus A_1)))+\mathsf E(N_\mathbf X(A_1\smallsetminus A_2)~N_\mathbf X(A_2\smallsetminus A_1))\end{align}$

Where

$\begin{align}A_1=[0,2]\times[0,4]\\A_2=[0,6]\times[0,2]\\A_1\cap A_2=[0,2]\times[0,2]\\A_1\smallsetminus A_2=[0,2]\times(2,4]\\A_2\smallsetminus A_1=(2,6]\times[0,2]\end{align}$